# Pandas: .nunique() overwrites original value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following code:

```
    isins = (
        collection.shareopenpositions_df.loc[
            :, ["number", "code", "isin"]
        ]
        .groupby(["number", "code"], as_index=False)["isin"]
        .nunique()
        .reset_index()
    )
```

I would like just a table with 4 columns: "number, code, isin, unique_isins"
What I get is 3 columns: number, code, isin
where isin is the total of occurancies, so I lost the value of ISIN itself

Is it possible to keep the value of the nunique?

Comment: `collection.shareopenpositions_df['unique_isins'] = collection.shareopenpositions_df[['number', 'code', 'isin']].groupby(["number", "code"], as_index=False)["isin"].transform('nunique')`

Comment: Is it ok if you also post a sample data?